# If K is infinite then $[K(x):K]=\mid K\mid$

Tags: field-theory

I have the following question in an algebra class.

If K is infinite then $[K(x):K]=\mid K\mid$
and I have hint: 1/(x-a) are linearly independent over K for all $a\in K$

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The hint gives you a lower bound on the degree of the field extension. On the other hand, the cardinality of $K(x)$ is equal to the cardinality of $K$ (provided both are infinite) since, for instance, $K(x)$ embeds into $K((x))$ which as a set is a countable product of copies of $K$. And certainly the cardinality of a vector space is an upper bound on its dimension!